# ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 47, column 27

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, parsing, parse-error

I have a program that takes a 452,793 xml files turns it into a pandas dataframe and then converts it into a .csv file... well its suppose to. It goes through the process of pulling information out of specific tags and inserting them into specific locations in the dataframe. But at file 6,274 of 452,793, it throws this error **"ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 47, column 27"** [error message picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfLDx.png)

I have already tried adding **encoding="utf-8-sig"** and **encoding="utf-8"** with no luck.

**Here is my code. Let me know if you need me to explain any of this.** There are indention errors. If there is anything not indented correctly it is because of stack overflows formatting when importing my code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import glob as glob
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import urllib.request as ur
import shutil
import zipfile
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

run = 0
globfiles = glob.glob("C:/Users/bbrown/Projects/Database/NSF/Trash/*.xml") 
glob.glob("C:/Users/bbrown/Projects/Database/NSF/Trash/*.xml") 
for file in globfiles: #The top portion
        run += 1
        print('globbing ',run, file)
        parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
        tree = ET.parse(file, parser)
        root = tree.getroot()
        x = []
        y = []

        for child in root:
            for child2 in child:
                x.append(child2.tag)
                y.append(child2.text)

        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            if x[i] == 'AwardTitle':
                data = [y[i]]
                df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['AwardTitle'])
            if x[i] == 'AwardEffectiveDate':
                data = [y[i]]
                df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =      ['AwardEffectiveDate'])
            if x[i] == 'AwardExpirationDate':
                data = [y[i]]
             df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['AwardExpirationDate'])
            if x[i] == 'AwardTotalIntnAmount':
                data = [y[i]]
                df4 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =      ['AwardTotalIntnAmount'])
            if x[i] == 'AwardAmount':
                data = [y[i]]
                df5 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['AwardAmount'])
            if x[i] == 'AbstractNarration':
                data = [y[i]]
                df6 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['AbstractNarration'])
            if x[i] == 'MinAmdLetterDate':
                data = [y[i]]
                df7 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['MinAmdLetterDate'])
            if x[i] == 'MaxAmdLetterDate': #index 10
                data = [y[i]]
                df8 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['MaxAmdLetterDate'])
            if x[i] == 'AwardID': #index 12
                data = [y[i]]
                df9 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['AwardID'])


        a = []
        b = []
        #0,1,6,7,8,9,10...22
        for child in root:
            for child2 in child:
                for child3 in child2:
                    a.append(child3.tag)
                    b.append(child3.text)

        for i in range(0, len(a)):
            if a[i] == 'Value':
                data = [b[i]]
                df10 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Value'])
            if a[i] == 'Code' and i == 1:
                data = [b[i]]
                df11 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Organization      Code'])
            if a[i] == 'SignBlockName':
                data = [b[i]]
                df12 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['SignBlockName'])
            if a[i] == 'FirstName':
                x = 0
                iterlist = []
                namelist = []
                for word in a:
                    if word == 'FirstName':
                        iterlist.append(x)
                    x += 1
                for eachnum in iterlist:
                    namelist.append(b[eachnum])
                data = [str(namelist)]
                df13 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['FirstName'])

            if a[i] == 'LastName':
                x = 0
                iterlist = []
                namelist = []
                for word in a:
                    if word == 'LastName':
                        iterlist.append(x)
                    x += 1
                for eachnum in iterlist:
                    namelist.append(b[eachnum])
                data = [str(namelist)]
                df14 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['LastName'])

            if a[i] == 'EmailAddress':
                x = 0
                iterlist = []
                namelist = []
                for word in a:
                    if word == 'EmailAddress':
                        iterlist.append(x)
                    x += 1
                for eachnum in iterlist:
                    namelist.append(b[eachnum])
                data = [str(namelist)]
                df15 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['EmailAddress'])

            if a[i] == 'StartDate':
                x = 0
                iterlist = []
                namelist = []
                for word in a:
                    if word == 'StartDate':
                        iterlist.append(x)
                    x += 1
                for eachnum in iterlist:
                    namelist.append(b[eachnum])
                data = [str(namelist)]
                df16 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['StartDate'])

            if a[i] == 'EndDate':
                x = 0
                iterlist = []
                namelist = []
                for word in a:
                    if word == 'EndDate':
                        iterlist.append(x)
                    x += 1
                for eachnum in iterlist:
                    namelist.append(b[eachnum])
                data = [str(namelist)]
                df17 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['EndDate'])

            if a[i] == 'RoleCode':
                x = 0
                iterlist = []
                namelist = []
                for word in a:
                    if word == 'RoleCode':
                        iterlist.append(x)
                    x += 1
                for eachnum in iterlist:
                    namelist.append(b[eachnum])
                data = [str(namelist)]
                df18 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['RoleCode'])

            if a[i] == 'Name':
                data = [b[i]]
                df19 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name'])

            if a[i] == 'CityName':
                data = [b[i]]
                df20 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['CityName'])

            if a[i] == 'ZipCode':
                data = [b[i]]
                df21 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ZipCode'])

            if a[i] == 'PhoneNumber':
                data = [b[i]]
                df22 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['PhoneNumber'])

            if a[i] == 'StreetAddress':
                data = [b[i]]
                df23 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['StreetAddress'])

            if a[i] == 'StateName':
                data = [b[i]]
                df24 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['StateName'])

            if a[i] == 'CountryName':
                data = [b[i]]
                df25 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['CountryName'])

            if a[i] == 'StateCode':
                data = [b[i]]
                df26 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['StateCode'])

            if a[i] == 'Code' and i != 1:
                x = 0
                iterlist = []
                namelist = []
                for word in a:
                    if word == 'Code':
                        iterlist.append(x)
                    x += 1
                for eachnum in iterlist:
                    if eachnum != 1:
                        value = b[eachnum],b[eachnum+1]
                        namelist.append(value)
                data = [str(namelist)]
                df27 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Codes'])

        aaa=[]
        bbb=[]
        for child in root:
            for child2 in child:
                aa.append(child2.tag)
                bb.append(child2.text)
                for child3 in child2:
                    a.append(child3.tag)
                    b.append(child3.text)
                    for child4 in child3:
                        aaa.append(child4.tag)
                        bbb.append(child4.text)

        dfvar = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, df11, df12, df13, df14, df15, df16, df17, df18,df19, df20, df21, df22, df23, df24, df25, df26, df27], axis=1)
    df = df.append(dfvar)
```

**You can download a sample of the xml file from here* - https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/download?DownloadFileName=2019&All=true

I just need it to stop throwing the error. Either by fixing whatever is causing it, or ignoring the error. Otherwise this is working golden!

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but according to Saxon/Xerces, all the files in your download parse without problems.

Comment: Take file number 6,274 and put it in a dedicated folder. Point the code `globfiles` to this folder. Run the code. Do you face the issue again? If you do post the problematic XML here.

Comment: I did a try statement before each file, and if they did not pass the try statement the program would continue onto the next file and add the file that gave an error to a list. Looking at the list after the program finished some of the xml files are messed up and not even in XML format. Thanks for your help!!